# How to get the array value from axios response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, axios

I am stuck for 4 hours for facing this problem. I have this code

```
var sttr = [];
      this.$http
      .post(this.api_url+url, data)
      .then((response)=>{
        sttr.push(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        if(error.request.status == 401){
          this.unauth();
        }else{
          sttr.push(error.response.data.errors);
        }
      });
      console.log(sttr[0]);
```

My response from both success and error is stored to the sttr variable. But the problem is when i want to get the first value of array, it's return undefined value. So, is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Can you log your response + your response.data ?
+ did you check that you did received a response and not an error ? If `error.request.status == 401` then you would not have had anything in sttr.

Comment: all data return well when i just log the sttr variable. But when i try to get sttr[0] it's return undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are actually calling `console.log(sttr[0]);` *before* the response comes back, because this code is async. You need to log it inside the `then` callback to ensure it happens after the response is received.

Comment: yeah i know, but when i do console.log(sttr). It's create output that i want

Comment: Anything else you want to do after the response comes back needs to wait for the promise. Your options are: to call other functions inside your `then` callback, or return the promise and chain more `.then` calls on that promise.

Answer (score 0):

execute the console.log(sttr[0]) inside 'then' callback will work i think. 
As you said in the comment that, console.log(sttr) is working, You can create a condition in the last part of your code.

```
if(sttr.length) {
  console.log(sttr[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there is still no way to return the data and save it to any variable